# does rstandard standardize in z?

Tags: r, residuals, standardization, diagnostic, lm

I'm new to R, so please be gentle.

I was under the impression that `rstandard(model)` returns the z-scores of the residuals in `model`. However, when I standardized the residuals myself in z, the result was different. In fact, `rstandard(model)` had a mean different from 0 and had a standard deviation different from 1. The differences seem to be nonnegligible. What exactly does `rstandard(model)` do? Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
> x = rnorm(30, mean = 100, sd = 15)
> y = rnorm(30, mean = 100, sd = 15)
> model = lm(y ~ x)
> z.res = residuals(model)/sd(residuals(model)) #standardizing it myself
> rstandard(model) - z.res #difference between rstandard and what i did
            1             2             3             4             5 
-4.422354e-04  1.556269e-04 -4.576832e-03 -1.274350e-03  1.048068e-01 
            6             7             8             9            10 
-2.333922e-02  1.820134e-02 -3.307542e-03  3.368978e-02 -1.804108e-04 
           11            12            13            14            15 
-1.100621e-01 -1.343715e-03 -1.300427e-03  1.509862e-03  3.246602e-03 
           16            17            18            19            20 
 3.734255e-03 -1.821539e-06 -1.153190e-02 -1.713254e-06 -2.185101e-02 
           21            22            23            24            25 
-2.681935e-02  2.562472e-03 -4.721114e-02 -1.084481e-04 -3.430827e-03 
           26            27            28            29            30 
 4.149684e-04  7.705807e-04  2.166815e-03  2.537837e-02  4.182761e-04 
> mean(z.res) 
[1] -9.428041e-18 
#as expected of z-scores, mean is 0
> sd(z.res)
[1] 1 
#as expected of z-scores standard deviation is 1
> mean(rstandard(model)) 
[1] -0.001990908
#not really 0
> sd(rstandard(model)) 
[1] 1.019699
#not really 1
```

Also, the way I understood [Standardized residuals in R's lm output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52522/standardized-residuals-in-rs-lm-output), `rstandard` is actually studentized residuals. But isn't there already `rstudent`?

I'm using R version 2.14.1 in Xubuntu 12.04.

Thank you.

Comment: The residuals don't have constant variance, even though the error term does. Points with more extreme 'x'-values have smaller variance. If you want to make them comparable, you don't divide by their *average* standard deviation, but by their individual standard deviation. This is what is going on. On the other hand, `rstudent` computes *externally* studentized residuals, not internally studentized residuals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rstandard()` produces standardised residuals via normalisation to unit variance using the overall error variance of the residuals/model.

`rstudent()` produces Studentized residuals in the same way, but it uses a leave-one-out estimate of the error variance.

The key line in `rstandard()` is

```
res <- infl$wt.res/(sd * sqrt(1 - infl$hat))
```

where `sd` is defined as

```
sqrt(deviance(model)/df.residual(model))
```

where `model` is the object returned by `lm`. But note this is not the same as `sd(resid(model))`

Note that the `sd` is also scaled by the hat values $1 - h_{ii}$ which together explain the discrepancy with your values.

The key line in `rstudent()` is

```
res <- res/(infl$sigma * sqrt(1 - infl$hat))
```

which is almost the same but `sd` is replaced via the leave-one-out estimate of the error variance (sd) `infl$sigma`

Answer (score 3):

The two functions do different things, as I understand it.

`residuals(model)` gives the response minus the fitted values. (from help for `lm`)

`rstandard(model)` is part of leave one out influence diagnostics (from help for `rstandard`), which says:

> This suite of functions can be used to compute some of the regression
>   (leave-one-out deletion) diagnostics for linear and generalized linear
>   models discussed in Belsley, Kuh and Welsch (1980), Cook and Weisberg
>   (1982), etc.

You can examine exactly what rstandard does by looking at the code. For lm, you can do this with

```
> methods(rstandard) 
> getAnywhere(rstandard.lm)
```

.

Comment: As `rstandard.lm` is exported from the `stats` namespace, you can just type its name at the prompt without needing `getAnywhere()`.